# SQL Query to select if a value from another exists in current table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables: Users, Rights and UserRights, which is mapping values from two first tables. Example:

Table 'Users'

| ID | LOGIN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 |
| 2 | test2 |

Table 'Rights'

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | read |
| 2 | write |

Table 'UserRights'

| USER_ID | RIGHT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

I need to check whether the user has the appropriate right and I need to output this information inline as true/false with delimiter for each right. So the result should look like this:

| LOGIN | RIGHTS |
| --- | --- |
| test1 | read=true;write=false |
| test2 | read=true;write=true |

I use Oracle Database

Now I'm using simple query with JOIN, but it's not applicable in current situation:

```
SELECT login,
       LISTAGG(name, ';') within GROUP (ORDER BY login) AS UserRights
FROM
  (SELECT u.login,
          r.name
   FROM UserRights ur
   RIGHT JOIN Users u ON ur.user_id = u.id
   LEFT JOIN Rights r ON ur.right_id = r.id)
GROUP BY login;
```

The output of this select looks like this:

| LOGIN | UserRights |
| --- | --- |
| test1 | read |
| test2 | read;write |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option: cross join `users` and `rights` (because you need to check all combinations), and then outer join it to `userrights` (because you want to check whether that particular combination exists or not).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  users (id, login) as
  3    (select 1, 'test1' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'test2' from dual
  5    ),
  6  rights (id, name) as
  7    (select 1, 'read'  from dual union all
  8     select 2, 'write' from dual
  9    ),
 10  userrights (user_id, right_id) as
 11    (select 1, 1 from dual union all
 12     select 2, 1 from dual union all
 13     select 2, 2 from dual
 14    )
```

Query:

```
 15  select u.login,
 16         listagg(r.name ||'='|| case when ur.user_id is not null then 'true' else 'false' end, '; ')
 17         within group (order by r.name) rights
 18  from users u cross join rights r
 19      left join userrights ur on ur.user_id = u.id and ur.right_id = r.id
 20  group by u.login;

LOGIN RIGHTS
----- ------------------------------
test1 read=true; write=false
test2 read=true; write=true

SQL>
```